# Hypothesis Testing, simple against composite.

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, data-analysis

i've got some trouble understanding this exercise from Amemiya's Introduction to statistics:

Given the density $f(x) = \frac{1}{\theta}$ from  $0 < x < \theta$, and 0 elsewhere, we are to test the hypothesis:
$H_0: \theta = 2$ against $H_1: \theta > 2$ by means of a single observed value of X. Consider the test which rejects $H_0$ if $X > c$. Determine c so that $\alpha = 0,25$ and draw the graph of its power function.

I'm having great trouble understanding this exercise, mostly because of the uniformly distributed density function. I know this is not hard but i'm used to a more "mechanic" approach to this kind of problems, and i haven't encountered a problem that used this kind of density function or simple against composite yet.

How would you start tackling this problem?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Like all hypothesis tests, you need to get a p-value ($p_c$) under the null hypothesis:

$p_c = P(X \geq c|\theta = 2)$ Your rejection region is the value of $c$ that makes $p_c =0.25$ Then, if your observed value is $>c$ then there is only a 25% chance of that happening if the max were in fact 2, so you would reject with a Type I error rate of 25%.

Comment: How would you go to find the value of $c$? i know exactly how would i do it with a normal distribution or a t-student, but every train of thought of how to get that with this kind of distribution seems wrong to me. 

I was thinking of just saying that the value would be $\theta*0,75$ but that doesn't seem right. As i'm not really including the $\theta=2$ or $\theta>2$ part of the problem.

I'm sorry for my english, as i just started studying abroad and i'm finding the math vocabulary much more harder.

Comment: You evalutae $p_c$ under $H_0$, so $c=2\times.75 = 1.5$ If $\theta = 2$ then $P(X\geq 1.5) = .25$. For example, imagine if X=1.99, the probability of getting so close to the maximum with just one trial is only $P(X\geq 1.99|\theta=2) = \frac{.01}{2} \ll .25$ so we would be very suspicious of $\theta = 2$

Comment: So that's pretty much it? the value of c is 1,5? I still have some trouble understanding the theorical background under this calculation: does it mean that when the single value is over 1,5 there's at least a 75% chance for $\theta$ to be over 2, so you reject the null hypothesis?

Again, i'm sorry if this seems a little dull-headed, but most of my doubts come actually from studying this in english rather than in my mother language

Comment: Note that if you looked at the $1-\alpha$ confidence interval for this test, you would get $[\frac{X}{.75},\infty)$, so the interval is one sided.

Comment: First, $\theta$ does not have a probability distribution. It is a fixed parameter...what varies is the data. With $\alpha = 0.25$ you are saying that if $\theta = 2$ you would want to reject only 25% of the time. Therefore, if X>1.5, you would reject $\theta = 2$ 25% of the time, when in fact $\theta = 2$  This is a Type I error. Note that this is not the most efficient test, as the resulting CI is infinitely long. If werer $H_1:\theta<2$ you would have a better test.

Comment: I know this is probably beyond this particular question, and it shows lack of understanding of this topic. 

Now i understand what you're saying, but when do we "incorporate" $H_1$ to the problem? is this already "in" the solution as the interval is one sided?

Comment: Yes the rejection region is determined by $H_1& if it were < 2 and not >2 then the rejection region would be different

Comment: I'm finally understanding, also, how would the Power function graph be? Is a concave down, increasing curve from y=0,25 to y=1 alright?

Comment: That is correct. Power is .25 at $\theta=2$ and increases to 1 as $\theta \rightarrow \infty$